# term_link filter gives less atributes

Tags: filters

I have made a filter for term_link but when I work with it, I get message about not getting the second and third attr. Its a pitty, i need them

```
add_filter('term_link','authorsongsurl',10);

function authorsongsurl($url,$term='',$taxonomy=''){

}
```

Whats up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the the fourth parameter, $accepted_args, to [add_filter()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to access the second and third parameters in your callback function. Only the first parameter ($url) is passed by default.

```
add_filter( 'term_link', 'authorsongsurl', 10, 3 );
```

The 3 in the end tells the filter to provide all the three parameters to your function.

Comment: NicE, now it works :)

Comment: Why, WordPress? Why?